# If condition not working properly in android eclipse

Tags: java, android

my code is

`int count = cur.getCount();
        if (count > 0)       // condition is true
            return true;

        else
            return false;   // excute this statement`

here count value is 1. and in if condition "count > 0" returns true. but also it jumb to else statement. if statement not excute. it returns false. can any one give a solution for this?

Comment: That's impossible. It returns twice? Are you calling it twice?

Comment: why not simply `return (count > 0);`?

Comment: its my own code. and ? : operator working properly. but why if else not working?

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
if (count > 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

or just put:

```
return count > 0;
```

Comment: what is the difference between your code and the code in the question.

Comment: this is the difference -> {

Comment: but for single line statement you don't need to use {

Comment: or just return (count > 0)

Comment: other all statement working properly like ? : (conditional operator), or direct return count>0. but why if else not working.

Comment: because of the empty row provided in your code between "return true;" and "else"

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue when special characters got in.
Delete everything and rewrite it (don't copy paste) and see if it still happens.
Also, try placing a watch on Count and see what the value is to identify exactly why the branch happens...